# Paypal API get payment confirmation

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I am able to post payment data to the Paypal REST API, and I get a response.
However, I ran some tests and entered incorrect expire dates and invorrect CVV2 numbers, but the response I get from the API is that the credit card has been approved.

From searching around, I understand that I should use the IPN to get a confirmation of the payment. I setup the IPN listener, and when I use the simulator to test, everything seems to be working.

My question is, how to I trigger the IPN callback on the payment? Or what would be the correct method to fully test the credit card details?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Comment: You can use any cvv and expire date in sandbox
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537295/test-credit-card-numbers-for-use-with-paypal-sandbox

Comment: ok good to know, does this mean that in the live environment it will return a failed response if the user enters incorrect cvv and expire date? how can I test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in live env., it will return the same failed response than a wrong card number.