# Paypal Sandbox saying CC is invalid

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

Anyone know why paypal is telling me to enter valid credit data and type? This is what I'm sending over to the sandbox.

USER=sandboxun

PWD=sandboxpw

SIGNATURE=sandboxSig

METHOD=DoDirectPayment

CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa

ACCT=4111111111111

EXPDATE=012020

CVV2=123

AMT=105.50

FIRSTNAME=John

LASTNAME=Doe

STREET=123 St

CITY=Sompelace

STATE=NE

COUNTRY=US

ZIP=68847

COUNTRYCODE=US

PAYMENTACTION=Sale

VERSION=2.3

I've also tried a valid number from one of my sandbox accounts and I still get the same cc info is invalid error.

Comment: Have you seen [Test credit card numbers for use with PayPal sandbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537295/test-credit-card-numbers-for-use-with-paypal-sandbox)?

Comment: Using one of those gives me this error.

Please use a different payment card.