# Paypal Test Credit Card Not Working In Test Mode

Tags: api, paypal, credit-card

I am using developing payment services in PayPal. I have the PayPal Manager account. I followed the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/). But at the time of payment with credit card the test credit cards nor any credit cards from the sandbox accounts are working. Following message appears.

What are the possible solutions?

[image]

Comment: have you tried with 4111 card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As using PayPal Manager. Make sure following setting for test are sets

1. Login Manager Paypal
2. Go to Service Settings > Set up
3. Add Sandbox email
4. And make access token to Yes

After Login to developer account of PayPal then go to the profile of the sandbox that is attached to manager account. Upgrade your sandbox Account Type to Pro

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue with a project a few months back.

Check out this comment it may be of use.

[Test credit card numbers for use with PayPal sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29819808/7830465)

Comment: I tried the solution but didnot work for me. Probably, in my paypal view there is no cvv or cvc fields.

Comment: did you try the card numbers at http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/testandgolive/tgl5103.html ? Those do not have cvv or cvc fields

Comment: Yes. But didn't work :( . I think there is some other problem. What does Please verify card details with your Bank in this means?

Comment: It just means that the card isn't validating against the paypal form. You're sure you're using your sandbox api credentials right? Are you able to process a test payment using one of the paypal accounts? I'm out of ideas otherwise.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you very much for your support :)